# how to see the relationship between tables in a schema (mysql)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I run a program that populates around 360 tables in a schema (lets say db007db),with all foreign keys and other relationship between tables. And i want to see the relationship of the tables in that schema like a EER diagram, is there any software or mysql client can do this?

Comment: You can use mysql workbench to draw eer diagrams with relationships.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the EER diagram with `MySQL workbench` at `Database Menu` -> `Reverse Engineer...`.
It can be messy when you have 360 tables.

Comment: Try to follow this guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-live.html